# Which ingredient in Cornitos Nacho Chips contains milk?

Tags: is-it-vegan, labeling

Cornitos Nacho Chips' (barbeque flavour) ingredients seem to be completely vegan, but it says just below, "Contains Soya and Milk Products".

Is it a misprint or does a ingredient contain milk?

[image: Ingredient and Nutritional Info]

[Cornitos Website](http://www.cornitos.in/products/a/nacho-crisps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ambiguous ingredient *Flavorings* is the most likely place to hide milk ingredients, assuming there are more flavours than just liquid smoke.

In general, I would trust the large text that says "CONTAINS MILK PRODUCTS" more than the ingredient list, where things are often renamed or hidden behind other names. But the only way to know for sure is to write the manufacturer and get a clarification.

If I were shopping for a vegan or somebody with a milk allergy, I would avoid this flavour.